# Can't See MVC5 Project Option in VS2012

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I have installed VS2012 update 4 and asp.net web tools. I have also installed windows 8.1 sdk and .net 4.5.1.

No matter if I select .net 4.5 or 4.5.1 there is no option to create a MVC5 project.

Does anyone know what I have missed?

Comment: Common problem, often asked. Please search this site for solutions and list everything you have tried before asking a new question.

Comment: Did you run the Web Platform Installer and install "Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools [version] for Visual Studio [version]" as listed in the duplicate?

Comment: ahhh my bad, I thought I had the latest version of web tools but I got it from an out dated page.  I got it working now, thanks for your patience and support.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. :) That's why it's important to show you followed all steps, you might have missed an important one!